# Stake split and private keys

Tags: staking

I am trying to understand how staking account split works on Solana in terms of wallets and private keys.
Let's assume I want to split my staking wallet with 100 SOL into 90 SOL and 10 SOL.

Do I have to create an empty staking wallet where I ask to put 10 SOL from my primary staking wallet? In this case I need to have my private key to the main wallet and public key to the second wallet?

OR

Does protocol creates a new staking wallet where it deposits 10 SOL and returns me keys to this new wallet?

Answer (score 1):

A stake account is an account that is created by your wallet, if you split your stake using the split stake instruction, it creates another stake account for the same wallet with the amount you want to split.

A single wallet can have as many stake account as wanted.

There is no extra "wallet" private key involved even though the transaction for the split process might or might not involve a random keypair under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

The split source account will look identical to the source account aside from the address and (maybe) delegation size.  The only keypair required* is a throwaway for reserving the new account's address.

* unless the new account is addressed by a PDA or the legacy `*WithSeed` address derivation scheme (please don't)

Comment: Why is *WithSeed no longer recommended?
It allows organising stake accounts sequentially